# Нужно выделять запятыми оборот с "как" в данном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как

*На Украине море проблем: уровень коррупции, несовершенство институтов, проблема собственности, проблема сбалансированности производства, проблема эффективности – все что угодно. Но говорить о каких-то выделенных моментах(,) как о катастрофических(,) я бы не стал.* Нужно выделять запятыми оборот с "как" в данном предложении?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да ни за что!

*Но говорить о каких-то выделенных моментах как о катастрофических я бы не стал.*

Тут другая проблема: в перечисление моря проблем не однажды закралось слово "проблема"; последнее и надо решать.

Answer (score 1):

Если поставите запятые (сравнение), получится такой смысл: 
*Говорить о выделенных моментах так, как мы (обычно) говорим о катастрофических.* Вы ведь не это хотели выразить?